# Internal SATA-HDD Doesn't Spin Up With Data Cable Connected

Tags: hard-drive, bios, motherboard, sata

What's happening here is beyond me and what I keep finding on the internet is talks about the PSU, but I doubt that it is my issue here. Then again I'm *not* a hardware person and the things I read may be too savvy for my end.

The thing is I had an old PC with an [Asus M4A785TD-V Evo](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/m4a785td-v%20evo/helpdesk_cpu/) board and a [Samsung HW153WI](https://www.hdsentinel.com/storageinfo_details.php?lang=1&model=SAMSUNG%20HD153WI) and that was working fine for years, I even had it running 24/7.

I have another PC with a [Gigabyte GA-F2A88XM-HD3P Rev. 1.0](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-F2A88XM-HD3P-rev-10/support) and a [Kingston SHSS3 240GB](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/SHSS3_us.pdf) that is also working fine.

Just recently a friend needed computer parts so I agreed to give him the first one, but I kept the Samsung plus the SATA-cable. I thought that I'd simply put the HDD in the second PC and would move on happily, but no.

From what I can tell the Samsung only spins up (praise those good old discs so I can at least confirm that) when *no* data cable is connected to it. Obviously I can't tell if everything else gets detected properly (partitions, OS, ...) as it's not listed in the BIOS. As soon as I plug in the data cable I can't hear it spinning up anymore.

I tried the mentioned data cable and also the one that the Kingston is connected with. I tried all eight internal SATA-ports without the Kingston connected, but I could never hear it spinning up.

I looked for newer BIOS-versions, but hey, there are only two (?), and I have the latest installed. The BIOS doesn't offer a lot of options IMHO and everything is set to SATA (no IDE or RAID). The list of SATA-devices only lists the Kingston no matter what I tried.

So in total it means to me:

- the HDD *can* spin up
- so the PSU seems fine (it has 420W and I only use on-board graphics)
- the data cables seem to be fine
- the motherboard generally has no SATA-issues because the Kingston keeps working

The only thing left in my thoughts is that the motherboard can't talk with the Samsung-drive for some reason. And then it's probably about protocols or something, maybe? Or is it something else entirely?

Can anyone please shed some light here and list pointers, please?

Comment: You might try an external SATA HDD enclosure, <US$10, for example https://www.amazon.com/s?k=external+sata+hdd+enclosure+usb&i=electronics , if nothing else works.

Comment: If your BIOS support "secure boot", try either turning it OFF or ON depending on its current value.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm trying to keep the HDD inside, so for now this isn't an option. Sorry for the delayed reply...

Comment: @cybernard I found something on how I could activate it (tell it to be "Windows 8" (?!), turn CSM off), but that didn't help. There were more options available then, but this was way beyond my understanding so I tried to undo what I did. I also tried to turn off Fast Boot, also with no improvement.

Comment: I would try a SATA to usb adapter that comes with its own power supply to verify the drive didn't die.  Is the drive in question currently, right now, show up in the BIOS of either PC that you have?

Comment: @cybernard I don't have the other PC anymore and it never showed up on the newer one.

Comment: which motherboard do you have?

Comment: @cybernard What do you mean? What info do you need that isn't in the question?

Comment: If I read your post correctly you have the Gigabit motherboard.  Please refer to page 25 in the manual and try setting all the BIOS settings listed there to Legacy Only.  If that fails go back and try UEFI only.